# AWS CDK: How to configure the parameters property for a SSM Assocation?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

My goal is to use the AWS Systems Manager State Manager to run a cron job that will shut down an RDS instance at 9PM. I'm in the process of building out the CloudFormation template using the AWS CDK.

The AWS CDK documentation for the CfnAssociation construct mentions the `parameters` property. It has a type of `any`. I'm trying to find an example of how to use the property.

Please help me to understand how to correctly add the parameter `AutomationAssumeRole` using this code snippet. `AutomationAssumeRole` expects the ARN for the role. For example, `arn:aws:iam::12345678999:role/StopStartRebootRDS`.

```
// Create the State Manager association that will shut down an RDS instance.
new ssm.CfnAssociation(this, 'StopRdsInstanceAssociation', {
  name: 'AWS-StopRdsInstance', // The document name to use.
  associationName: 'StopRdsInstance', // A user friendly name for this association.
  documentVersion: '$DEFAULT', // I'm guessing this will work. Not sure yet.
  instanceId: dbInstance.instanceIdentifier, // The RDS database that will be shut down.
  scheduleExpression: '0 00 21 ? * * *', // Daily at 9PM.
  parameters: {}, // What does this look like?
});
```

Your guidance is appreciated.

## What I've tried

I thought I could create an SSM parameter and populate it with the Role ARN. But this is just wrong. I'm not sure how else to set this up. The error from this configuration is below.

```
const automationAssumeRole = new ssm.CfnParameter(this, 'RdsParameter', {
  type: 'String',
  value: role.roleArn,
});

// Create the State Manager association that will shut down an RDS instance.
new ssm.CfnAssociation(this, 'StopRdsInstanceAssociation', {
  name: 'AWS-StopRdsInstance',
  associationName: 'StopRdsInstance',
  documentVersion: '$DEFAULT',
  instanceId: dbInstance.instanceIdentifier,
  scheduleExpression: '0 00 21 ? * * *',
  parameters: {
    automationAssumeRole,
  },
});
```

> Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Trying to resolve() a Construct at /Resources/${Token[InfrastructureDev.RdsStack.StopRdsInstanceAssociation.LogicalID.762]}/Properties/parameters/automationAssumeRole/node..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the role's ARN directly.  The parameter key names should be in Pascal Case.

```js
new ssm.CfnAssociation(this, "StopRdsAssociation", {
  name: "AWS-StopRdsInstance",
  associationName: "StopRdsInstance",
  scheduleExpression: "cron(0 00 2 ? * * *)",
  parameters: {
    InstanceId: [dbInstance.instanceIdentifier],
    AutomationAssumeRole: [role.roleArn],
  },
});
```

Based on the AWS blog post [Schedule Amazon RDS stop and start using AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-systems-manager/), the instance id and role are sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @fedonev, this didn't work due to a bug in the code. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Github issue [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4057) that discusses this very issue. After reviewing a proposed workaround, I'm going to use an "escape hatch" to apply the changes. I was able to get this working using the following:

```
// Create the State Manager association that will shut down an RDS instance.
const association = new ssm.CfnAssociation(this, 'StopRdsInstanceAssociation', {
  name: 'AWS-StopRdsInstance',
  associationName: 'StopRdsInstance',
  scheduleExpression: 'cron(0 00 2 ? * * *)',
});

// Use an escape hatch to set the parameters. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4057
association.addPropertyOverride('Parameters.InstanceId', [dbInstance.instanceIdentifier]);
association.addPropertyOverride('Parameters.AutomationAssumeRole', [role.roleArn]);
```

### Update

I'd like to leave this for historical purposes, but @fedonev's solution is working for me. No escape hatch needed.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!  BTW, the issue (from 2019) must have since been resolved.  The revised code in my answer deploys successfully.  No escape hatch required.

Comment: Great! Thank you for following up. I originally made a mess of the construct and something else must have been masking the real problem. For example, my cron was in the wrong format, I opted not to use the Target property and InstanceId property (attached directly to the association). Stripping out these helped to make some progress.